# How do I create a Sobject instance in JavaScript, on a Lightning Component controller, to pass to the Apex controller?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, sobject, casting

I have a lightning component from which I pass some values to a controller. I want to pass the object as a variable and update a field on this object.

How do I make the object variable? See my example below:

#### Lightning

```
var action = component.get("c.updateRecord");
action.setParams({
    "objId": getCurrentRecord,
     "obj": object,
    "selection" : selectedValues,
    "fieldName" : field
});
```

#### Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static object updateRecord(object obj, id objId , string selection, string fieldName){
        system.debug('obj-->' + obj);

        object objNew = obj;
        objNew objupdate = [SELECT id, fieldName FROM objNew WHERE id = :objId][0];
        objupdate.+fieldName = :selection;

        update objupdate;
        return objupdate;
    }
}
```

#### Update

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static string updateRecord(string objNew, id objId , string selection, string fieldName){
        sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objNew).newSObject() ;
        sObj objupdate = [SELECT id, fieldName FROM sObj WHERE id = :objId];

        objupdate.+fieldName = :selection;

        update objupdate;
        return objupdate;
    }
```

Comment: what does this meant you are passing sObjectName or Object ` " object objNew = obj; objNew objupdate = [SELECT id, fieldName FROM objNew WHERE id = :objId][0];`  it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @vignesh I want to pass the object as a string variable and update the corresponding Id. See my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here.

- Create a object attribute in Lightning and use that to update the values.

`<aura:attribute name="expense" type="Expense__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Expense__c' }"/>` and then get it in controller.

```
var expenses = component.get("v.expense");

var action = component.get("c.saveExpense");
  action.setParams({ 
      "expense": expense
  });
  if (callback) {
      action.setCallback(this, callback);
  }
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Apex class

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Expense__c saveExpense(Expense__c expense) {
    // Perform isUpdateable() check here 
    upsert expense;
    return expense;
}
```

- Second, if you are passing object API name in string, Then in apex class create new instance and use that

  `sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objNew).newSObject() ;
  sobj.put();//put the data
  //perform DML.`

Comment: I want to pas the object indeed as a string. I tried this but get Invalid type see:public static string updateRecord(string objNew, id objId , string selection, string fieldName){
        sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objNew).newSObject() ;
        sObj objupdate = [SELECT id, fieldName FROM sObj WHERE id = :objId];

Comment: @Thomas you need dynamic SOQL here. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Define a attribute in your component of type sobject whichever you want:-

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact"
        default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }" />
```

Then in your javaScript controller, call your method and set the parameter as follows:-

```
var saveContactAction = component.get("c.saveContactWithAccount");
            saveContactAction.setParams({
                "contact": component.get("v.newContact"), //you were doing wrong here
                "accountId": component.get("v.recordId")
            });
```

And in your apex controller you can get the parameter:-

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact saveContactWithAccount(Contact contact, Id accountId) {
        contact.AccountId = accountId;
        upsert contact;
        return contact;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This makes the object static. I want to have a variable object which I pas as a parameter trough the lightning design, see my update